# Code does not work as intended (Palindrome checker)

Tags: java, char, palindrome

I am trying to check if a string is a palindrome, but it seems it does not work, because when I send a string that I know is not a palindrome, it returns that it is a palindrome, can anyone help? It also won't add to the variable *counter*.

```
package UnaryStack.RubCol1183;

public class CheckPalindrome {

static int counter = 0;

/** Decides whether the parentheses, brackets, and braces
in a string occur in left/right pairs.
@param expression a string to be checked
@return true if the delimiters are paired correctly */
public static boolean checkBalance(String expression)
{
    StackInterface<Character> temporaryStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
    StackInterface<Character> reverseStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
    StackInterface<Character> originalStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();


    int characterCount = expression.length();
    boolean isBalanced = true;
    int index = 0;
    char nextCharacter = ' ';


    for (;(index < characterCount); index++)
    {
        nextCharacter = expression.charAt(index);
        switch (nextCharacter)
        {
        case '.': case '?': case '!': case '\'': case ' ': case ',':
            break;
        default: 
        {
            {
                reverseStack.push(nextCharacter);
                temporaryStack.push(nextCharacter);
                originalStack.push(temporaryStack.pop());
            }

            {
                char letter1 = Character.toLowerCase(originalStack.pop());
                char letter2 = Character.toLowerCase(reverseStack.pop());
                isBalanced = isPaired(letter1, letter2);
                if(isBalanced == false){
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        } // end switch
    } // end for
    return isBalanced;
} // end checkBalance

// Returns true if the given characters, open and close, form a pair
// of parentheses, brackets, or braces.
private static boolean isPaired(char open, char close)
{
    return (open == close);
} // end isPaired

public static int counter(){
    return counter;
}


}//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the errors in logic that were found inside the method checkBalace() and finished the code into a full working one. Here is what my finished code looks like:

```
public class CheckPalindrome {

static int counter;

/** Decides whether the parentheses, brackets, and braces
in a string occur in left/right pairs.
@param expression a string to be checked
@return true if the delimiters are paired correctly */
public static boolean checkBalance(String expression)
{
    counter = 0;
     StackInterface<Character> temporaryStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
     StackInterface<Character> reverseStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
     StackInterface<Character> originalStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();

     boolean isBalanced = true;

    int characterCount = expression.length();

    int index = 0;
    char nextCharacter = ' ';


    for (;(index < characterCount); index++)
    {
        nextCharacter = expression.charAt(index);
        switch (nextCharacter)
        {
        case '.': case '?': case '!': case '\'': case ' ': case ',':
            break;
        default: 
        {
            {
                reverseStack.push(nextCharacter);
                temporaryStack.push(nextCharacter);

            }

            break;
        }
        } // end switch


} // end for

while(!temporaryStack.isEmpty()){
    originalStack.push(temporaryStack.pop());
}

while(!originalStack.isEmpty()){
    char letter1 = Character.toLowerCase(originalStack.pop());
    char letter2 = Character.toLowerCase(reverseStack.pop());
    isBalanced = isPaired(letter1, letter2);
    if(isBalanced == false){
        counter++;
    }
}


    return isBalanced;
} // end checkBalance

// Returns true if the given characters, open and close, form a pair
// of parentheses, brackets, or braces.
private static boolean isPaired(char open, char close)
{
    return (open == close);
} // end isPaired

public static int counter(){
    return counter;
}


}
```

I used 2 while methods outside of the *for* thus fixing the logic errors pointed out. I also assigned the value 0 to *counter* inside the method to fix a small problem I encountered. Feel free to revise the code if I still have errors, but I think I made no errors, then again, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems way more complex than it needs to be.

```
//Check for invalid characters first if needed.
StackInterface<Character> stack = new LinkedStack<Character>();

for (char ch: expression.toCharArray()) {
    Character curr = new Character(ch);
    Character peek = (Character)(stack.peek());
    if(!stack.isEmpty() && peek.equals(curr)) {
        stack.pop();
    } else {
        stack.push(curr)
    }
}
return stack.isEmpty();
```

---

Honestly using a stack is over kill here. I would use the following method.

```
int i = 0;
int j = expression.length() - 1;
while(j > i) {
    if(expression.charAt(i++) != expression.charAt(j--)) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You put exaclty the same elemets in reverseStack and originalStack, because everything you push into the temporaryStack will be immediately pushed into originalStack. This does not make sense.

```
reverseStack.push(nextCharacter);
temporaryStack.push(nextCharacter);
originalStack.push(temporaryStack.pop());
```

Therefore the expression

```
isBalanced = isPaired(letter1, letter2);
```

will always return true.